# Not sure what is meant by Quadratic Matrix. Is this an academic, or domain-specific term?

Tags: matrices, quadratics

I'm not a mathematician, and the last time I studied maths was a good eight years ago. I'm going through a book called '*An Introduction to Recommender Systems*', and in `section 2.4.1` it refers to `table 2.4`  (see image below)

[Table 2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzflV.jpg)

It says "*Because the 4 x 4-matrix M in Table 2.4 is quadratic, U, E, and V are also quadratic 4 x 4 matrices*"

I'm not quite sure how a conclusion was drawn that the matrix is 'quadratic'. I can't find anything describing what a 'quadratic matrix' is via Google. I would assume that it is a way to describe a matrix of numbers that have been squared, but that's not the case in `table 2.4` above as these numbers were introduced as single values at the start of this chapter, and have not been squared since then.

**Would anybody mind telling me if this is an obscure mathematics, or academic term? And/or what it means?**

Here's the full page, if anybody is interested in viewing it in context.

[Full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/datGP.jpg)

Reference: (Felfernig, A. et al., Recommender Systems: An Introduction, New York, Cambridge University Press, 2011)

Comment: A rectangle with side length $4\times 4$ is quadratic. So a matrix with $n$ column and $m$ rows is called **quadratic** if $m=n$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. A quadratic matrix is a numerical table with the same number of rows and columns. And without sounding too patronizing: My recommendation for you is to study some linear algebra before going on with this book. This is a basic requirement for any serious study of data science.

Comment: The more usual  term is $\color{green}{\text{square matrix}}$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks everyone for the information! :) I would like to upvote your comments but it appears I can't due to low reputation...

Comment: I'm familiar with the concepts of a *square matrix* and a *quadratic matrix equation*, but I've never heard of a "quadratic matrix". The authors seem to have taken some liberties with their terminology...

Comment: "Quadratic matrix" as a term for square matrices may come from literal translation of the German "quadratischen Matrix".  See, for example, de.wikipedia's "matrix" entry ("Stimmen Zeilen- und Spaltenanzahl überein, so spricht man von einer quadratischen Matrix").  I've also seen the term in another article with a German author.